# window.setInterval() does no work properly in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval

i used setInterval() function in angular.js controller to show timer on UI later. create a scope variable which have value of inactivity in seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){ scope.timer++ }, 1000);
```

what it suppose to do is, it should update screen every second. but it doesn't. some time it update screen after two seconds, three seconds and sometime it update it every seconds, but its not consistent. 
while when I log scope. timer value it behaves properly.

what would be the problem of this. Does angular.js restrict native javascript somehow or what?
[image]

Comment: For additional reference: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Answer (score 1):

Better is to use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval), example:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.timer = 0;
    $interval(function() { $scope.timer++; }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-bind="timer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scope.$apply

```
setInterval(function(){ scope.timer++; scope.$apply(); }, 1000);
```

setInterval is not angular function so scope is not refreshing.

Or use angular service ( prefered solution ):

```
$interval(function(){ scope.timer++;},1000);
```

Comment: I believe using $interval is preferred and recommended than doing $apply in this case

Comment: Yee @GopinathShiva thanks for comment i updated answer

Comment: Appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

May be the value is updating in the `controller` but not in the `DOM`
try this

**JS**

```
setInterval(function(){ 
 scope.timer++ 
 setTimeout(function(){
   $scope.$apply();
 }, 1);
}, 1000);
```

Or you can use `$interval` and you are following my answer you can use `$timeout` instead of setTimeout also

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Update your code to this

```
$interval(function(){
    $scope.timer++;
}, 1000)
```

Make sure that your `$scope.timer` is correctly initialized

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` is not an angular function, hence the scope is not refreshed, I DO NOT RECOMMEND using `scope.$apply()` as its wasteful.

use angular's inbuilt `$interval` method:

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$interval',
  function($scope, $interval) {
      stop = $interval(function() {
          $scope.timer++;
      }, 1000);
});
```

documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Angular's `$interval`, from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

You have to add it to your controller and use it, like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/q3iQljigftZFiwuNjqM0?p=preview) ( view Plunker )

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
  var count = 1;
  $scope.count = count;
  $interval(function() {
    $scope.count++;
  }, 1000);
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval is a JS native function, to execute it inside the digest loop you should call the apply() method or alternatively use the wrapper $interval as suggested in the AngularJS doc.

```
$interval(function(){ scope.timer++ }, 1000);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval